# Github not updating by commit and push to the repo from xcode sourcecontrol

Tags: xcode, git, github

I cloned the project from repository and working on the project. When i tried to create new files and done some work tried to push the code to repository in the Github. When i commit and push the code using source control to the origin master it was done successfully and didn't show any error. And when one of my team member tried to pull the code from the repository the files i created my team member didn't get them. And when i check the repo the some are committed and some are not committed to the repository and also team person got some files into the local repository but not into the xcode.

Can anyone please tell what i did wrong and what should i do to resolve this issues.
Can anyone please help me solve this issue.

And thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use command line ? Did you commit your files in the git root dir ?

Comment: Initial i used command line. And later on from xcode i did it using source control .